# Execute task in background in JavaFX

Tags: service, task, javafx-2

I want to load up to nine panels in a TilePane. For each pane I have to first run a computation of the content (about 300ms) and then I have to build the Panel (about 500ms).

What I want is, that there are nine ProgressIndicators which exchanges with every panel after its computation.

I tried it with the `Platform.runLater` command as well as with a service class. The result was always the same. The ProgressIndicator are shown, but not animated. After seconds there are all panels at once.

Is there a possibility, that the Indicators are animated the whole time and that I can exchange them one after another?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

JavaFX has Event Dispatch Thread which it uses for UI events. All work with UI should happen on this thread. And non-UI calculations shouldn't happen there to avoid lags in UI.

See next code:

```
public class Indicators extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane root = new HBox();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 100));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(0);
            root.getChildren().add(pi);

            // separate non-FX thread
            new Thread() {

                // runnable for that thread
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        try {
                            // imitating work
                            Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000));
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        final double progress = i*0.05;
                        // update ProgressIndicator on FX thread
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                pi.setProgress(progress);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }

        stage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sergey...I have a question, I can have several of these threads running in the application?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, It is advisable to have several Platform.runLater in the application??. Since these threads have to change the view, for exampe whether to display a dialog.

Comment: @MarcoR sure, just don't do anything except updating UI in those runLater calls because there is only one UI thread and nothing will happen there until your runLater is done.

Answer (score 20):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Minimal extends Application {

private TilePane loadPane;
private ProgressIndicator[] indicators = new ProgressIndicator[9];
private Label loading[] = new Label[9];
private Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK,Color.BLUE,Color.CRIMSON,Color.DARKCYAN,Color.FORESTGREEN,Color.GOLD,Color.HOTPINK,Color.INDIGO,Color.KHAKI};
private int counter = 0;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    //creating Layout
    final Group root = new Group();                             
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);            
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    StackPane waitingPane = new StackPane();
    final ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();
    Label load = new Label("loading things...");
    progress.setTranslateY(-25);
    load.setTranslateY(25);
    waitingPane.getChildren().addAll(new Rectangle(400,400,Color.WHITE),load,progress);
    root.getChildren().add(waitingPane);

    //Task for computing the Panels:
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                final double prog = i*0.05;
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progress.setProgress(prog);
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    //stateProperty for Task:
    task.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable,
                State oldValue, Worker.State newState) {
            if(newState==Worker.State.SUCCEEDED){
                loadPanels(root);
            }
        }
    });

    //start Task
    new Thread(task).start();

    primaryStage.show();
}

private void loadPanels(Group root) {
    //change to loadPanel:
    root.getChildren().set(0,createLoadPane());

    //Service:
    final Service<Rectangle> RecBuilder = new Service<Rectangle>() {
          @Override protected Task<Rectangle> createTask() {
              return new Task<Rectangle>() {
                  @Override protected Rectangle call() throws InterruptedException {
                      updateMessage("loading rectangle . . .");
                      updateProgress(0, 10);
                      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                      }
                      updateMessage("Finish!");
                      return new Rectangle((380)/3,(380)/3,colors[counter]);
                  }
              };
          }
    };

    //StateListener
    RecBuilder.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue,
                        Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            switch (newState) {
            case SCHEDULED:
                break;
            case READY:
            case RUNNING:
                break;
            case SUCCEEDED:
                Rectangle rec = RecBuilder.valueProperty().getValue();
                indicators[counter].progressProperty().unbind();
                loading[counter].textProperty().unbind();
                loadPane.getChildren().set(counter, rec);
                if(counter<8){
                    counter++;
                    nextPane(RecBuilder);
                }
                break;
            case CANCELLED:
            case FAILED:
                loading[counter].textProperty().unbind();
                loading[counter].setText("Failed!");
                if(counter<8){
                    counter++;
                    nextPane(RecBuilder);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    //begin PanelBuilding:
    nextPane(RecBuilder);
}

private void nextPane(Service<Rectangle> recBuilder) {
    loading[counter].textProperty().bind(recBuilder.messageProperty());
    indicators[counter].visibleProperty().bind(recBuilder.progressProperty().isNotEqualTo(new SimpleDoubleProperty(ProgressBar.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)));
    recBuilder.restart();
}

private Node createLoadPane() {
    loadPane = new TilePane(5,5);
    loadPane.setPrefColumns(3);
    loadPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        StackPane waitingPane = new StackPane();
        Rectangle background = new Rectangle((380)/3, (380)/3, Color.WHITE);
        indicators[i] = new ProgressIndicator();
        indicators[i].setPrefSize(50, 50);
        indicators[i].setMaxSize(50, 50);
        indicators[i].setTranslateY(-25);
        indicators[i].setTranslateX(-10);
        loading[i] = new Label();
        loading[i].setTranslateY(25);
        waitingPane.getChildren().addAll(background,indicators[i],loading[i]);
        loadPane.getChildren().add(waitingPane);
    }

    return loadPane;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the issue is that a task (better a single task-instance) can't run multiple times. Placing the task instance in a method which let's reinitialize it by every method call solved it for me, too. Nice :)

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is by using lambdas and thread.

```
private void logIn() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        //CONNECT TO WEB AND LOG IN (ON OUT OF FX THREAD)
        boolean loginSuccess = new LogIn(emial.getText(), pass.getText()).execute();

        //DO SOMETHING WITH CONTROLLS ON FX THREAD ACCORDING RESULT OF OVER
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (loginSuccess) {
                info.setText("SUCCESS");
                info.setTextFill(Color.web("#268515"));
            } else {
                info.setText("FAIL");
                info.setTextFill(Color.web("#CD000E"));
            }
        });
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Other answer to this questions seem to not use the Task class which is specifically made for this purpose.  The answer that does use it, I feel isn't following the best practices in some spots.

Here is my cleanup of Yggdrasil's answer (which I believe to be the best so far).  Specific changes are:

- Don't use Platform.runLater to update progress from within a Task's call method when Task already has a `progress` property with an `updateProgress` method)
- Override `succeeded` and `failed` methods of Task rather than adding a state listener
- Try to encapsulate state in the Task, e.g. the index of the square it is computing
- Fixed a state issue that caused every other rectangle computation to fail
- Added random failures to show UI updates for a failing task
- Fixed progress update in the service-based tasks
- minor adjustments to layout code

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AsyncProgress extends Application {
    static final Random rng = new Random();
    private Group root;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private TilePane loadPane;
    private ProgressIndicator[] indicators = new ProgressIndicator[9];
    private Label loading[] = new Label[9];
    private Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.CRIMSON, Color.DARKCYAN, Color.FORESTGREEN, Color.GOLD, Color.HOTPINK, Color.INDIGO, Color.KHAKI};
    private int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //creating Layout
        root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        progress = new ProgressBar();
        Label load = new Label("loading things...");
        VBox waitingPane = new VBox(10, load, progress);
        waitingPane.setPrefSize(400, 400);
        waitingPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().add(waitingPane);

        //Task for computing the Panels:
        Task<Void> panelTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                updateProgress(0, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    sleep(rng.nextInt(500));
                    updateProgress(i * 0.05, 1);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded() {
                loadPanels();
            }

        };

        progress.progressProperty().bind(panelTask.progressProperty());

        primaryStage.show();

        var t = new Thread(panelTask);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }

    private void loadPanels() {
        progress.progressProperty().unbind();
        root.getChildren().set(0, createLoadPane());

        final Service<Rectangle> recBuilderService = new Service<Rectangle>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Rectangle> createTask() {
                return new Task<Rectangle>() {
                    private int squareIndex = counter++;

                    @Override
                    protected Rectangle call() {
                        updateMessage("loading rectangle . . .");
                        updateProgress(0, 10);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                            sleep(100);
                            if (rng.nextDouble() > 0.95) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Rectangle failed to load.");
                            }
                            updateProgress(i + 1, 10);
                        }
                        updateMessage("Finish!");
                        return new Rectangle((380) / 3, (380) / 3, colors[squareIndex]);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void succeeded() {
                        setRectangle(squareIndex, getValue());
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void failed() {
                        failRectangle(squareIndex, getException());
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        recBuilderService.stateProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldState, newState) -> {
            switch (newState) {
                case SUCCEEDED:
                case FAILED:
                    if (counter <= 8) {
                        nextPane(recBuilderService);
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });

        // kickstart the panel building
        nextPane(recBuilderService);
    }

    private void nextPane(Service<Rectangle> recBuilder) {
        loading[counter].textProperty().bind(recBuilder.messageProperty());
        var prog = indicators[counter];
        prog.visibleProperty().bind(prog.progressProperty().isNotEqualTo(ProgressBar.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS, 0));
        prog.progressProperty().bind(recBuilder.progressProperty());
        recBuilder.restart();
    }

    private void failRectangle(int index, Throwable reason) {
        var tt = new Tooltip(reason.getMessage());
        var msg = loading[index];
        msg.setTooltip(tt);
        msg.textProperty().unbind();
        msg.setText("Failed!");
        var ind = indicators[index];
        ind.progressProperty().unbind();
        ind.setTooltip(tt);
    }

    private void setRectangle(int index, Rectangle rec) {
        indicators[index].progressProperty().unbind();
        var lab = loading[index];
        lab.textProperty().unbind();
        loadPane.getChildren().set(index, rec);
    }

    private Node createLoadPane() {
        loadPane = new TilePane(5, 5);
        loadPane.setPrefColumns(3);
        loadPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            Rectangle background = new Rectangle(380 / 3, 380 / 3, Color.WHITE);
            indicators[i] = new ProgressIndicator();
            indicators[i].setPrefSize(50, 50);
            indicators[i].setMaxSize(50, 50);
            loading[i] = new Label();
            loading[i].setTranslateY(35);
            StackPane waitingPane = new StackPane(background, indicators[i], loading[i]);
            waitingPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            loadPane.getChildren().add(waitingPane);
        }

        return loadPane;
    }

    static void sleep(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```