# Submitting a background job and updating stage with result

Tags: javafx-2

I'm a complete noob with JavaFX 2 - (started this morning with a HelloWorld that I'm adapting).

I need to update a Text node with the result of a background thread. Is there anything special I need to be aware of with JavaFX2 or is it simply enough to submit a callable and update the text. A pointer to a tutorial would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After calculating the results, running the

```
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Update the text node with calculated results
            }
       });
```

at the end of the same background thread is enough in normal situations. This link also maybe helpful:
[Execute task in background in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9165251/682495).

Answer (score 2):

`Platform.runLater()` will run later on the JavaFX application thread - which is fine if the executed content is a quick running task (e.g. inexpensive computation without I/O or just a call to update the UI).  Use a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) for animation or timer based things.  Otherwise a [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) or [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) based solution, for which there is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).  Don't ever read or write from objects involved in an active scenegraph (even updates triggered by binds) off of the JavaFX application thread.  Some further discussion and examples are in this [forum thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2308759).