# How can I run javafx components with Java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

How can I run javafx components with Java thread from the run() method? Is it even supported at all? Thanks!

Comment: try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165251/execute-task-in-background-in-javafx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying a live scene from any thread other than `Application` thread is not allowed. If you want to do that from a `java.lang.Thread` then somewhere in your implementation of the `run()` you need this:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    // change your scene graph here
  }
});
```

That causes all your changes to happen on the `Application` thread. If you have a task that is to execute repeatedly, have a look at `javafx.concurrent.Service<V>`. The docs say:

> As part of the JavaFX UI library, the Service knows about the JavaFX
>   Application thread and is designed to relieve the application
>   developer from the burden of manging multithreaded code that interacts
>   with the user interface.